# Firestore polygons don't print separately on google map. Help me find the fault & make it right

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dgnt.png)I have polygons saved to firestore database as arrays which hold GeoPoints collection. Each document has one polygon saved as an array of GeoPoints but when I get these polygon documents printed on google map, they don't print on map as individual polygons but print on map as a whole/one polygon. I have several polygon in firestore which I need to see separately on google map.
I am writing an e-commerce app and I have to use these polygons as shipping/delivery zones. I have multiple shipping/delivery zones and for each zone I need to print it on map separately.

something must be wrong. help me find the problem and print these polygons separately on google map from firestore.

here is my code, please review this code and help me find the problem.

```
      mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map_polygon) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
}

override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap
    mMap.uiSettings.isMyLocationButtonEnabled
    mMap.uiSettings.isCompassEnabled
    mMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled
    mMap.uiSettings.isMapToolbarEnabled
    mMap.uiSettings.setAllGesturesEnabled(true)
    mMap.uiSettings.isZoomGesturesEnabled
    mMap.uiSettings.isMyLocationButtonEnabled
    mMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this.requireContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this.requireContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {

        return
    }
    mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true

    class polygons {
        val polygon: ArrayList<*>? = null
    }
    var geoList: MutableCollection<GeoPoint>
    val pointsList: MutableList<LatLng> = ArrayList()
    db.collection("deliveryzones").get().addOnSuccessListener { it ->
        if (it != null) {
            for (i in it.toObjects(polygons::class.java)) {
                geoList =  i.polygon as MutableCollection<GeoPoint>
                geoList.forEach {
                    it.latitude
                    it.longitude
                    val latlongPoints = LatLng(it.latitude, it.longitude)
                    pointsList.addAll(listOf(latlongPoints))
                }
                mMap.addPolygon(PolygonOptions().addAll(pointsList).strokeColor(Color.BLUE))

            }

        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Can you please provide an example for this statement *they don't print on map as individual polygons but print on map as a whole/one polygon*. Please also show us the what is the expected result.

Comment: I have edited the question and pasted a screenshot of polygons

Comment: Are you sure you are adding the coordinates in the correct order?

Comment: Yes, they are perfectly in the correct order. Problem seems to be in the loop of GeoPoints which draws multiple polygons as one polygon. You can review the code I posted. Try it yourself. It will draw multiple polygons as one polygon that is the problem.

Comment: I am running for loop to get the coordinates of polygons in all documents as you can see in my code. they should be drawing as separate polygons on google map.